# H2 Database query grammar

Tags: sql, h2

I am running the below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_MODEL 
WHERE "name"  = "Administrator"
```

However, I am getting an error message, not sure why the value is also considered a column name.

> Column "Administrator" not found; SQL statement:

When I tried to use single quotes.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_MODEL 
WHERE "name"  = 'Administrator'
```

Then H2 again complains

> Literals of this kind are not allowed; SQL statement:

When the name is not enclosed double-quotes. The H2 converts the column name into the upper case.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_MODEL 
WHERE name  = "Administrator"
```

> Column "NAME" not found; SQL statement:

Need help on how H2 query works.

Answer (score 1):

You must use this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_MODEL 
WHERE name = 'Administrator'
```

Comment: H2 does not allow single quotes.
Secondly, if i give name it converts it into upper case and searches for column NAME. and gives error.

Comment: Are you sure? SQL Grammar (http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#expression) suggests that it does.

Comment: yeah am sure.. :(

Answer (score 0):

So, finally got the solution, I had to execute SET ALLOW_LITERALS ALL. to allow single quotes in my query.

By default h2 has disabled this to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: In H2 all literals are allowed by default, such error message can appear only when they were disabled explicitly.